# Redirect wrong after form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am started learning Ruby. I just followed this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html to create blog app. One thing I noticed if we try to submit the form without entering data from  url  http://localhost:3000/articles/new it showing error message and redirect to http://localhost:3000/articles

I think it should keep same url and show error message.
Not sure how to fix that.

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

      if @article.save
        redirect_to @article
      else
        render 'new'
      end 
  end   

    private
      def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
      end  

end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

    resources :articles
    root 'welcome#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

rails routes

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)     welcome#index
     articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
              POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
  new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
 edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
      article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
              PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
         root GET    /                            welcome#index
```

Comment: When your form renders errors, it's not technically a redirect. When you submit the form, it does a `POST /articles`. When there's a validation error, your controller then `renders 'new'`. That means you'll remain on `/articles`. You could change this to redirect instead, but then your form wouldn't display errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard behavior. If you want to change it however to keep the URL, you can modify the `new` and `create` actions:

```
def new
  if article_params
    create
    return
  end
  @article = Article.new
  render 'new'
end 

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

And in routes.rb:

```
resources :articles
post "articles/new"
```

Comment: Sorry just got error msg: ActionController::ParameterMissing in ArticlesController#new. Extracted source (around line #33):
 params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text

Answer (score 1):

@Shannon answer is correct, I'm writing this for your comment on his answer, Try to use `model` argument, according to [this](https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a) when you gonna use `model: @article` it will generate everything automatically for you

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Amr, I am already using that in the form _form.html.erb. <%= form_with model: @article, local: true do |form| %> .. But I am still geting error and Not sure why.. I think to say:   "if article_params" is that wrong?